# Can't re-open "Group My Tabs" page after killing Firefox

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-12.04

Due to memory problems I closed Firefox whilst the `Group My Tabs` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) feature was displaying the multiple tab groups. After 20 minutes the process still hadn't finished so `killall firefox`ed it.

When I restart Firefox, there is a Javascript process called `tabview.js` that hangs unless I click `Stop` at the warning screen. If I do hit `Stop` then I can no longer open the tabview, so I can't get to any of the tabs except in the subgroup I was last looking at.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make the `Group My Tabs` come back, but if you can remember some of the details of a tab in another subgroup, you can access that subgroup with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, then typing enough of a prompt in the location bar (url bar  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) to get Firefox to display the "Switch to open tab" option. For example if you have [Facts on the Distribution of Earnings, Income, and Wealth in the United States [PDF]](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:CkgTAtMQD_4J:www.minneapolisfed.org/research/qr/qr3411.pdf+&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjEkD7IFG8-CahQjolX0SQOPNjJvmTw-49Dtm7UOrp3MUOLCbu0IdmvXytVtPYjX8EmqWHOSR6o2sXHr7P9XQP-y2L0sgN8PWyTlk1Eqf4MXx2Ohpm96DzIGGLYhOKAuyivmWz9&sig=AHIEtbSDrQGYkSwNKxdvvOx3z-F2DAO3qw&embedded=TRUE) open in another subgroup, then open a new tab and type `Minneapolis` and it should show the option to switch to that pdf tab, even if it's hidden by the lack of  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.